# Print array from a preg_split

Tags: php, preg-split

Hi I trying to print the content of a array.

This is the code:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $pattern = '[<td[^>]*>(.*?)</td>]';
    $content = preg_split( $pattern, $row['introtext'], NULL );
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td align="center" valign="top" class="table-cursos-links">';
    echo  $n++; 
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center" valign="top" class="table-cursos-links">';
    echo  '<a target="_parent" href="http://cttcorp.hexasystems.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$row['id'].':'.$row[alias].'&catid='.$row['catid'].'">'.$row['title'].' </a>'; 
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center" valign="top" class="table-cursos-links">'. $content[2] .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
```

It doesn't print anything. Any Idea?

Comment: I know the problem is the regex, basically I just want the text inside the <td> and </td>

Answer (score 0):

> know the problem is the regex, basically I just want the text inside the <td> and </td>

Well then you have the right regex, but are using it wrong. When using [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split) everything matched by the regex will be **removed**. If your `$row['introtext']` contained something like `_<td>data</td>_` then you will receive an array with two empty strings or whitespace or other leftovers.

Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) instead.

```
preg_split( $pattern, $row['introtext'], $match );

print $match[1];
```